# how to determine if objects children has children

Tags: php, object

I have an object defined below:

```
    $userAttributes->deviceInfo->macAddress->type = "text";
    $userAttributes->deviceInfo->macAddress->required = "*";
    $userAttributes->deviceInfo->macAddress->options = NULL;
    $userAttributes->deviceInfo->macAddress->size = "16";

    $userAttributes->callControl->guest->isActive->type = "select";
    $userAttributes->callControl->guest->isActive->required = "*";
    $userAttributes->callControl->guest->isActive->options = $tF;
    $userAttributes->callControl->guest->isActive->size = NULL;
```

if i do:

```
   foreach ($userAttributes as $key => $value)
   {
       foreach ($value as $k => $v)
       {
            echo $v->type;
            echo $v->required;
            echo $v->options;
            echo $v->size;
       }
   }
```

this is going to fail when it gets to the callControl piece.  how can i determine if $v-> has children?  The property "isActive" could be any number of things so i cant assume anything and do $v->isActive->Blah

how can i determine if $v-> has children and if so iterate through that?

Comment: Use `php is_array` to determine if it is an array. http://us3.php.net/is_array

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a duplicate of [the manual](http://nl1.php.net/property_exists)

Comment: Well, `is_object()` in this case

Comment: why dont you check if it's an object ? `if (is_object($v->)) { //do foreach`. maybe create a recursive function..

Comment: Sorry, Sam is right, use is_object();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP has a built in function to check if something is an object. It's called `is_object` and it checks if the parameter that you pass to it is an object.

Further reading: http://php.net/manual/es/function.is-object.php

For your specific case you can create a function to call it recursively:

```
   function getAttributes($obj){
        foreach($obj as $k => $v){
            if(is_object($v)){
                getAttributes($v);
            }else{
                echo $v;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: are you missing ""$this->""getAttributes($v);   ?

Comment: @bart2puck `$this->` is not necessary because I'm just doing a call of the same function, `$this->` is used to refer to an attribute or a method of an instance, `getAttributes()` is just a function.